# Raspberry pi camera module enable "Raspistill"

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi

I want to use Raspberry PI's system command `raspistill`to take images in a c program, the program line is: `system("raspistill -q 5 -vf -hf -o pic1.jpg -t 1 -th 0:0:0");`

However, when I run the program sometimes error occurs, 
it shows that:

> mmal_vc_component_enable- failed to enable component- ENOSPC
>     mmal- camera component couldn't be enabled
>     mmal- main- Failed to create camera component
>     mmal- Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updatesckquote

And I have tried to add some parameters into /boot/config.txt:

> gpu_mem=128   start_file=start_x.elf   fixup_file=fixup_x.dat
>   disable_camera_led=1   cam_lwm=16   cam_hwm=32   cam_offline_start=16

However the error still always occurs sometimes (sometimes ok). I really want to solve this problem in order to continue my project. What should I do?

Comment: Same thing here, I am upping the memory allocated to the GPU to 512 but no difference :-/

Comment: I've noticed that you sometimes get this when setting the quality too low as well as too high. Have you tried increasing the quality?

Answer (score 4):

Stop any other processes using the camera (e.g.raspimjpeg)

```
$ ps -aux
```

// locate the process pid and kill it using the pid number (e.g. 764)

```
$ sudo kill 764
```

Note: You might have more than one process running so be sure to kill them all before trying again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I ran the following on a Pi 4 model B

```
vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1

raspistill -w 3280 -h 2464 -n -t 2000 -o test.png
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

make: *** [makefile:27: raspistill] Error 70
```

It turned out to be the camera. The standard camera works!

Answer (score 1):

This error will appear when the RPi Camera is "On" and is streaming. The component: ENOSPC cannot start unless the RPi Camera is not streaming or being used by another process.
One solution is to try to stop the Camera stream before the Snapshot and then restart it after.

Answer (score 1):

finally i can solve this problem after a lot of hours troubleshooting.

I already share it in my YouTube (https://youtu.be/on8UlkRvLok)

This problem only occur in camera raspberry pi V2.1 (IMX219) from **Element14**. But in camera raspberry pi V2.1 from **OKdo**, i don't get this error

So, the solution when error
"mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates"

You **need some initialization** with a works camera (me camera from **OKdo**).
So, the step is

1. Plug your works camera to Raspberry Pi (me using Raspberry Pi 4B)
2. Turn on your Raspberry Pi
3. check "vcgencmd get_camera" to make sure your hardware is detected the camera
4. capture image using "raspistill -v" and camera will capture the image
5. Then replace the works camera with ENOSPC Error Camera (from **Element14**)
6. then try to capture the image "raspistill -v" and the ENOSPC Error will not occur

**Notes:**

- But, after the ENOSPC Error Camera works, and then you restart/shutdown the raspberry pi, the error will occur again :(

OS Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4GB)

- Linux raspberrypi 5.10.60-v7l+ #1449 SMP Wed Aug 25 15:00:44 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you use I/O during camera recording operation.
I faced the same issue on using used I/O while recording.
So you can either add before recording or after not in between.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and I had faced the same issue.
My solution was to **set the GPU Memory from 128 to 256** in the Raspberry Pi Configuration.